# Copying a `System.Guid` to `byte[]` without allocating

Tags: c#, memory, optimization

The application I'm working on is very focused on performance, and as such needs to keep allocations down to a minimum to keep GC stalls down.

I was surprised to find that `System.Guid` does not expose any method to copy it's `byte[]` representation into an existing buffer. The only existing method, `Guid.ToByteArray()`, performs a `new byte[]` allocation, and otherwise there's no way to get at the underlying bytes without it.

So what I'm looking for is some way to copy a `Guid` to a an already existing `byte[]` buffer without allocating any memory (since `Guid` is a value type already).

Comment: D you really need `Guid`? Maybe just directly create `[DllImport("ole32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern int CoCreateGuid(byte[] guid);` (or http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/rpcrt4/UuidCreateSequential.html) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. The problem is not that I need to create a Guid, but that I already have an instance of a Guid that I need to get into an existing byte array without allocating an intermediate buffer.

Comment: Note in a gc language this allocation costs almost nothing ( incrementing the nursery pointer) .  pinvoke or even fixed are likely ot be far more expansive unless  your working  on a larrge numbe rin one op

Comment: The allocation isn't what hurts you. It's the eventual garbage collection that costs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I settled on came from some help from the [Jil project](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil/blob/71fc65c4148f1aa25fdf9a5fc166e51f91865ec9/Jil/Deserialize/Methods.cs#L36) by [Kevin Montrose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80572/kevin-montrose). I didn't go with that exact solution, but it inspired me to come up with something that I think is fairly elegant.

**Note:** The following code uses [Fixed Size Buffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx) and requires that your project be built with the `/unsafe` switch (and in all likelihood requires Full Trust to run).

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
unsafe struct GuidBuffer
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    fixed long buffer[2];

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Guid Guid;

    public GuidBuffer(Guid guid)
        : this()
    {
        Guid = guid;
    }

    public void CopyTo(byte[] dest, int offset)
    {
        if (dest.Length - offset < 16)
            throw new ArgumentException("Destination buffer is too small");

        fixed (byte* bDestRoot = dest)
        fixed (long* bSrc = buffer)
        {
            byte* bDestOffset = bDestRoot + offset;
            long* bDest = (long*)bDestOffset;

            bDest[0] = bSrc[0];
            bDest[1] = bSrc[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
var myGuid = Guid.NewGuid(); // however you get it
var guidBuffer = new GuidBuffer(myGuid);

var buffer = new buffer[16];
guidBuffer.CopyTo(buffer, 0);
```

Timing this yielded an average duration of 1-2 *ticks* for the copy. Should be fast enough for most any application.

However, if you want to eke out the absolute *best* performance, one possibility (suggested by Kevin) is to ensure that the `offset` parameter is `long`-aligned (on an 8-byte boundary). My particular use case favors memory over speed, but if speed is the most important thing that would be a good way to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

If speed is the main consideration, you can shave a good bit of time by using the `Guid` directly instead going through the `GuidBuffer` struct.  Here's the extension method I'm using.

```
public static unsafe void Encode(this byte[] array, int offset, Guid value)
{
    if (array.Length - offset < 16) throw new ArgumentException("buffer too small");

    fixed (byte* pArray = array)
    {
        var pGuid = (long*)&value;
        var pDest = (long*)(pArray + offset);
        pDest[0] = pGuid[0];
        pDest[1] = pGuid[1];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var guid  = Guid.NewGuid();
var array = new byte[16];
array.Encode(0, guid);
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as it's been a while, but there _was_ some reason why I couldn't rely on using `System.Guid` directly. If that's not currently the case, then great tip!

Comment: @rossipedia, if you happen to remember the sticking point, I would appreciate knowing what that was, even if it's OBE.  That said, ReSharper helped me a lot to get to the final version I've listed above.  I'm not sure I could have done it without that help.

Comment: @rossipedia, and by the way, I couldn't have done it without spring boarding off your answer.  So thank you.